# How to move dfs data to a new disk

Tags: hadoop

[newbie question on Hadoop]

I currently have a single node implementation of hadoop 2.7.2.
The machine is running out of disk space:
`df -h` gives

```
Filesystem  Size   Used   Avail  Use%    Mounted on
/dev/vdb    50G    39G    12G    78%     /app
```

As soon as the usage percentage goes up to 80%, the cluster hangs. Therefore, I should add more disk to the machine.

What would be the best way to increase the disk space?

**Approach A:**

- Add a new disk (`/dev/vdc`)
- Mount it to whatever folder (e.g. `/hadoop_data`)
- update `hdfs-site.xml` to add a `dfs.datanode.data.dir` node pointing to the mount point

**Downsides of approach A:**

- does not prevent the first configured folder from getting full
- kind of 'messy' since all the data are scattered across several mount points

**Approach B:**

- stop hadoop
- Add a new disk(`/dev/vdc`)
- Mount this new disk as `/app_new`
- rsync between `/edx` and `/app_new`
- swap the mount points between the two disks
- start hadoop

**Downside of Approach B:**

- if hadoop keeps any reference to the disk ID, this will probably ot work

What would be the 'cleanest' option?
Is there a third way?

Comment: Ideally, you should add more nodes before adding more disks. Then you run the rebalancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Approach A.

Just add bit more steps:

Mention the directory name in Datanodes Directory, so that your cluster gets aware that you have added a new Datanode directory.

Now, Simply run HDFS balancer command and then data will be equally be shifted to both the Datanodes and your error will be gone.

Comment: The intranode balancer doesn't exist in Hadoop2